# Debug support for multiple Docker nodes in vscode

Tags: node.js, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a node.js project using Docker that I am trying to debug in Visual Studio Code. I am able to debug the project if one node is deployed using `docker-compose up`, but if I try to deploy multiple replicas using `docker-compose up --scale node=3` I run into the following error:

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: port is already allocated
```

This error is occurring since there are multiple nodes all trying to attach to port 9229. Is there any way to dynamically allocate a port range for debugging instead?

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000" 
      - "9229:9229"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: node.local
      NODE_ENV: development
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 3000
```

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "restart": true,
      "port": 9229,
      "address": "0.0.0.0",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/home/node/app",
      "protocol": "inspector"
    }
  ]
}
```

Snippet from package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 -L src/index.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to treat port `9229` the same way you treat port `3000`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000" 
      - "9229"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: node.local
      NODE_ENV: development
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 3000
```

When you don't specify a host port, Docker will select a  random port on the host; you can see these in `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID   ...   STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                NAMES
404f6b766136   ...   Up 2 seconds    8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49163->3000/tcp, :::49163->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49162->9229/tcp, :::49162->9229/tcp   example_node_3
7e16271b1dea   ...   Up 2 seconds    8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49161->3000/tcp, :::49161->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49160->9229/tcp, :::49160->9229/tcp   example_node_2
1117a0762bdf   ...   Up 11 seconds   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49159->3000/tcp, :::49159->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49158->9229/tcp, :::49158->9229/tcp   example_node_1
```

From the above `docker ps` output, we can see that if we want to reach port 9229 on container `example_node_1`, we need to use port `49158`. If we want `example_node_2`, we need port `49160`, etc.

That may be all you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this solution works great. In case anyone sees this, for the solution to work you need to change the port value in launch.json to match the port allocated for the container i.e. `"port": 49158,`

Comment: If this solved your problem, consider checking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers!